# HTTPS endpoint request returns as Mixed Content HTTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, http, https

I am having issues returning API data from a GET request for a secure HTTPS Strava API endpoint. I use the following jQuery request:

```
$.get(`https://strava.com/api/v3/athletes/249995/activities?access_token=[access token here]/`, function(data, status) {
  console.log(data[0].name);
}, 'json');
```

I expect the data to be returned, but instead I'm getting a Mixed Content error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mitchellgsides.github.io/Strava-PR-Lister/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.strava.com/api/v3/athletes/249995/activities?access_token=[access token here]'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I can follow the exact requested link:

```
https://strava.com/api/v3/athletes/{id}/activities?access_token={accesstoken}/
```

with no issues, and the result shows as a secure HTTPS with what I want, but my app won't load the content. How can I get rid of the mixed content error, when that error shouldn't apply because the content IS served over HTTPS?

Comment: It looks like Strava are redirecting your HTTPS request to a HTTP URL, as such there's nothing you can do about the warning. Either that or you have a typo in your URL somewhere and you're not actually sending the HTTPS request as you believe you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it! Since I didn't specify 'www.' in my request, the request was redirected as HTTP. In order to avoid redirection, I've made the request identical, like this:

> https://www.strava.com/...

instead of

> https://strava.com/...